# pe: inputNumber max length can not larger than 13

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm using Pe: InputNumber tag in my project, the code is listed like below:

```
<pe:inputNumber id="transferAccountInputBoxId" styleClass="input-amount-box" thousandSeparator="" maxlength="20" value="#{transferAccountsFlow.accountsInput}" rendered="#{inputPageRenderController.accountsInputBoxRenderer}">
</pe:inputNumber>
```

But it seems that the value I set for maxlength, it doesn't work at all.
It only can type 13 digits in this input box, but actually i want to type 20 digits.

Is this a bug for this Primefaces Extension tag or not?

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not implemented. Please create a feature request.
NOTE: pe:inputNumber was moved to PrimeFaces.